# Log scale plot in matplotlib with zero value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data with zero values on log scale in matplotlib, and everything works fine, with the zero values going to negative infinity on log scale. However, I want matplotlib to conisder log(0) as NaN as Matlab does and remove the vertical line that extends to negative axis. I can try to tweak the data, but does anyone know if there is a way to set this up in matplotlib?[Matlab plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7otko.png)
[Matplotlib plot: The vertical line extends to negative axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbL5e.png)

Matplotlib MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
mpl.rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
## for Palatino and other serif fonts use:
#rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
params = {'text.latex.preamble': [r'\usepackage{siunitx}',
                                  r'\usepackage{upgreek}']
                                  }
mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 1.0
plt.rcParams.update(params) 

xvalue = np.array([0.00e+00, 1.00e-03, 2.00e-03, 3.00e-03, 4.00e-03, 5.00e-03,
       6.00e-03, 7.00e-03, 8.00e-03, 9.00e-03, 1.04e-02, 1.25e-02,
       1.55e-02, 1.98e-02, 2.60e-02, 3.49e-02, 4.78e-02, 6.64e-02,
       9.31e-02, 1.32e-01, 1.87e-01, 2.67e-01, 3.82e-01, 5.47e-01,
       7.86e-01, 1.13e+00])

yvalue = np.array([0.0000e+00, 1.0227e+22, 1.0716e+22, 1.0993e+22, 1.1030e+22,
       1.0979e+22, 1.0892e+22, 1.0781e+22, 1.0642e+22, 1.0495e+22,
       1.0292e+22, 1.0020e+22, 9.6677e+21, 9.2294e+21, 8.7119e+21,
       8.1418e+21, 7.5712e+21, 7.0841e+21, 6.8074e+21, 6.9572e+21,
       8.0212e+21, 1.1639e+22, 2.8571e+22, 1.3637e+25, 8.0409e+24,
       5.5016e+24])




fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(xvalue,yvalue,'-',color='#1f78b4',linewidth=1.0)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=5.0,pad=0.5)
ax.set_xlim([-0.1,1])
ax.set_xticks([0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])
ax.set_yscale('log') 
ax.set_ylim([1e21,1e26]) 
ax.grid(linestyle='dashed')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{Xlabel}$',fontsize=4.5)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\mathrm{Ylabel}$',fontsize=4.5)
```

Comment: can you provide the code you are working with?

Comment: This is a deliberate feature. If you do not want to show a value, you can always exclude it from the data prior to plotting.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for your comment. Indeed, I can exclude the data prior to plotting. However, I was wondering if matplotlib has this feature (Matlab seems to have it).

Comment: I would see it the way that it's a bug in matlab, which is not happening in matplotlib.

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez I have added the matplotlib MWE.